# How to configure DITA DTD to VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, dita

I want to see DITA validations working for my file. How do I implement a DTD? for example,

Comment: What do you mean by "configure to VS Code"? Please [edit] to clarify. What do you expect to observe once "configuring to VS Code" is successful?

Comment: I want to see DITA validations working for my file. How do I implement a DTD? for example,
<!DOCTYPE topic PUBLIC "-//OASIS//DTD DITA Topic//EN" "topic.dtd">

Comment: Please always [edit] clarifications into your question post instead of hiding them in the comments! Comments are for _soliciting_ clarifications- not for providing them.

Comment: Done. Can you provide me the solution for the problem?

Comment: your edit is incomplete. And no, I cannot answer your question. [Wait patiently](/help/no-one-answers) for someone who can.